# Can't update column with name 'routing'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table with attribute "routing" and I can't update any record's routing value.

I tried to call `DB::getQueryLog()` and it prints update query without the routing field. But when I rename the column, it works fine.

Comment: Can you please post your migration where you try to change the column name?

Comment: @party-ring I changed via phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, I figured it out. I have a setter for routing in my model. Commenting it solved my problem.